# Trying to figure out if / how Cloud would be an advantage

Tags: object, cloud, buckets

Compared to plain vanilla PhP/MySQL, what's the upside of Cloud?

A typical block of contents would be approximately 30,000 snippets of text, each 300 characters or less in length.

I'm looking at some good documents on buckets and objects and wondering if there's any reason for me to dive into all that.

Just a rough idea would be appreciated. Am I barking up the wrong tree even thinking of Cloud for this?

p.s. just guessing: is the way to go to run MySQL in the Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the cloud service you choose. On the cloud you can choose between an IaaS, a PaaS or a SaaS.

On an IaaS you will get an infrastructure as a service where you need to install MySQL, the web server, ...

On a PaaS, all these services could be enabled just with click of your mouse and you will just use the service without taking care of the config or the installation process.

This blog [article](http://www.comtechies.com/2013/03/how-to-create-and-connect-cloudbees.html#.UbBACECpqvs) will give you an idea about how to use a MySQL database on a PaaS.

Regarding the web server, for PHP could be something really easy like zip your project and use a command to deploy your application without any config. See [here](https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/PHP) an example.

Comment: Thanks Haddock, but was asking less for how to than for what's the advantage.
I've trolled around some but haven't found a simple description of what the up-side is.

Comment: Advantage is that: don't need infrastructure; don't need to manage the stack/database...; can concentrate in development and not in infrastructure; you can usually easily set-up complex services like high-availability that will be difficult to have on premise;

Comment: Yes indeed. And load leveling ... and ability to add resources on the fly. I was thinking more about the specific I sketched above i.e. 30K small snippets of text.
In general terms it's the way to go, I know. But I don't have clue 1 about performance.